# WPF - XAML - Help me fix TabControl template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use TabControl template from MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx

Everything works fine until TabStripPlacement comes into the game.
Setting TabStripPlacement to “Left” doesn’t work. I’m getting this result.

[image]

While I need this template works with horizontal and vertical tab placement.
I’m not so familiar with styling and templates please help me to resolve this.

**EDIT:**

I expect this result when TabStripPlacement is set to “Top”

[image]

And this when TabStripPlacement is set to “Left”

[image]

Just like a normal TabControl

Comment: It seems that you have the tabs inside a Grid.Row and the main "panel" inside a second Grid.Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `TabControl` template you lniked is an example, not the default.

You need to expand the `Grid` in the template to be 2x2 instead of 1x2, then create a series of `Triggers` that set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` of the `TabPanel` named `HeaderPanel`, and the `Border` object containing the content based on the `TabStripPlacement`

You can look at the actual default `TabControl.Template` by extracting the template using Expression Blend, or using the tool like [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091). It contains the triggers you'll want.

Comment: That works indeed. I just thought Microsoft would not publish “incorrect” example.

Comment: @NazarGrynko It's not really "incorrect", its just an example so its not completely full-featured. Glad that worked out for you though :)

Comment: @NazarGrynko It can be misleading, but they're doing it right, IMO. If you're looking up an example of how to use a control, a fully-featured template is probably going to be completely overwhelming.  A simple, stripped down example is enough to get you started.